# UiPath Assistant no longer opens

Tags: uipath, uipath-studio, uipath-orchestrator, uipath-activity, uipath-api

I recently just started using UiPath and it as been smooth sailing until 2 days ago when I tried to open UiPath Assistant and it no longer opens and doesn't show an error message, I have tried reinstalling but it still does not work, this problem happens on a Remote Desktop, the one I have installed on my PC is still okay, both are community editions. is there a fix for this or anyone who has experienced this before who can help me?

I have tried ending all tasks related to the program, also tried reinstalling.

Comment: What are the Windows System Events saying?

Comment: it shows Error in the System Events and this is the information on the error, UiPath.Executor 23.6.1.0 
Child Executor with pid 7576 exiting because root process with pid 13112 exited.